# Exportar documento a excel con PHP

Tags: php

¿Es posible exportar una tabla de un sitio a un documento excel? Pero con el formato nuevo, que he visto códigos similares a esto:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=InformeVentas.xls");
?>
```

Pero lo he probado y exporta al formato de excel 97-2003. ¿Existe alguna manera de que sea con el nuevo formato *(.xlsx)* pero sin usar librerías como por ejemplo PHPExcel o PHPSpreadSheet, solamente usando el código de php.

Comment: No se si has resuelto el problema, pero estoy tratando de hacer los mismo y lo que hice fue colocar la extensión `.xlsx` y funciono. Lo estoy tratando de resolver es que en GoogleDrive me muestras el formato `html` de las tablas.

Comment: @Stn. Si tambien habia probado así, pero no funcionaba, al exportarlo decía que el formato del documento no era reconocible.

Comment: Es una pena, pero es bueno saberlo ya que uso linux y no he probado abrirlo todavía en windows. Si lo he hecho en google drive, pero me importa todo el código html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debo decirte que no he hallado dicha forma, te recomiendo usar [PhpSpreadSheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

ejemplo facil y sencillo :

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola capaz este no se a el medio pero necesito ayuda, yo tengo una pagina web donde le cargo un numero y me tira en otra solapa un archivo .php, mi pregunta es la siguiente, saben si existe la posibilidad si cargando ese numero en excel me devuelve el o los valores del .php que uno necesite? no se si fui claro, espero me puedan ayudar